# p:editor is disabled in modal dialog with appendToBody="true"

Tags: java, primefaces

```
<p:commandButton id="composeBtn" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-document"
        oncomplete="composeDlg.show()" update=":frmCompose ,:frmCompose:dlgpnl">
</p:commandButton>


<p:dialog widgetVar="composeDlg" modal="true" id="dlgcompose"
    appendToBody="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">

        <h:form id="frmCompose" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p:editor widgetVar="editor" value="#{newMail.body}" />

        <p:separator>
        <p:commandButton value="# erLbl['mailBox.cmdSend']}" ajex="false"
                action="#{pc_mailBean.submit()}" update=":frm:msg"
                oncomplete="composeDlg.hide()" />
        <p:commandButton value="#{commonLbl['cmdCancel']}"
                oncomplete="composeDlg.hide()" />

    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

When I click the compose button the **dialog appeasr** but the **editor** is **Disabled**. I'm updating the form used in the dialog.

Comment: the commandButton is in a different form? you are not nesting forms, are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is any runtime error in binding bean so if any error in backing bean for **example**    **Object is not initialize**...etc runtime error that's why the editor is appear as disable...

**So please read carefully any simple runtime error is create problem for model dialog which is appandToBody="true".**